# android Picker how to use in RTL its not moving position when i use

Tags: react-native

android react-native picker is not moving position while we switch RTL its  looking like english only i want to show in RTL   i am using below picker

```
  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
  <Picker
    selectedValue={selectedValue}
    style={{ height: 50, width: 150 }}
    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedValue(itemValue)}
  >
    <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
    <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
  </Picker>
</View>
```

https://paste.pics/9122J

Answer (score 0):

Just add `flexDirection:"row"` to your `View` style

**Note:**

you should use

[react-native-material-dropdown] https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-dropdown

because this dropdown automatically handle RTL

Comment: i updated my view  with styles still its same  can you please let me whats wrong see this https://paste.pics/9122J

Comment: I thought you want to change the position of picker w.r.t to RTL but you want to change the picker content position which is not possible. but you can try to add transform: [{ rotateX: '-360deg'},{
        rotateY:"-180deg"}] to picker style

Comment: after using transform i can see selected number is showing reverse https://paste.pics/9142V

Comment: use react-native-material-dropdown because I am using this in one of my projects with Arabic language support. RTL support is automatically handled in this library

Comment: you can see my project screenshot here https://paste.pics/914XT